# PayUMoney integration redirects to localhost

Tags: php, redirect, payumoney

I've downloaded the php script for test payment and added my MERCHANT_KEY and SALT.

Downloaded this script:
https://github.com/payumoney-india/PayUMoney_PHP_Module/archive/master.zip

After submitting the form it redirects to the payumoney website but after sometime it redirects to localhost instead of the payment page.

I'm stuck on this. Could you please help me?

1. After submitting form:
   https://screenshots.firefox.com/XV6RJC3C70xpGIch/null
2. After sometime it redirects to:
   https://screenshots.firefox.com/ZBLNLGav3Choptky/null

Answer (score 1):

Its basically because you're on the testing URL. You have to change the URL to production or live. For testing purpose payu gives you this test url. If you see the comment on PayUMoney_form.php

```
// **End point - change to https://secure.payu.in for LIVE mode**
$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";
```

Read the comment. I also got the same issue and got to know that it is staging test.

Answer (score 1):

Please use secure.payu.in url which is mentioned in the comment. Then provide your merchat details inside the script and it works .

Comment: How can I check in test environment? Is it'll give me submit test transactions?

Comment: I got the solution. I have to use the specific merchant key and salt for test environment. Test Key - rjQUPktU Test Salt - e5iIg1jwi8. It solved the issue but still I can't complete the payment. Getting following error:
 Your previous attempt failed. Please try again below.

Comment: It might be because of multiple attempts.

Comment: No. I got the same error also today. 
 https://screenshots.firefox.com/ARNPQYlng3gjN4dG/null
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The salt and key they provided for the test account is not correct , use these salt and key for test account

here are the salt and key just copy and paste these:

```
$SALT = 'e5iIg1jwi8';
$key = 'rjQUPktU';
$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";
```